# Python MySql connector raises SyntaxError when creating table

Tags: python, mysql

Here is a function in my program

```
def OrderTable():
        c = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'pass', database = 'storeroomps')
        cur = c.cursor()
        tbl = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDER(
        ORDER_NO CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        ORDER_DATE CHAR(10),
        ORDER_STATUS CHAR(5),
        CUST_NO CHAR(20),
        ITEM_ID INT
        )'''
        cur.execute(tbl)
        c.close()
```

when I execute the function I get this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER(
                ORDER_NO CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                ORDER_DATE CHAR(10),
                ORDER_STATUS CHAR(' at line 1
```

I have another identical function which creates a manufacturer's table

```
def ManufTable():
        c = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'pass', database = 'storeroomps')
        cur = c.cursor()
        tbl = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MANU(
        M_NAME CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        M_CODE CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        M_EMAIL CHAR(20),
        M_STATUS CHAR(5),
        ITEM_ID INT,
        ORDER_NO CHAR(20)
        )'''
        cur.execute(tbl)
        c.close()
```

this one works fine but the order one raises the syntax error? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Avoid [MySQL keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O) like `ORDER` for table or column identifiers. Also, avoid abbreviations like `MANU` for readability and maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER is a SQL keyword (e.g. ORDER BY).

You might try changing the name of your table. Change it to CUSTOMER_ORDER and see if it works.